# How to search a file in multiple jars

Tags: command-line, java, search

Want to search a file inside a set of jar files. How this can be done in ubuntu termianl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand that you want to look for a specific file -- and not search for a string *within* a file in the .jar archive.

Another option, without zipgrep, just with zip, sed and friends. Suppose you want to look through jar files in the current directory:

```
for i in *.jar ; do unzip -l "$i" | sed "s?.*?$i: &?" ; done | grep "filetofind"
```

Answer (score 1):

To search from terminal see this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770183/list-contents-of-multiple-jar-files)

To do that from GUI, download [jar-explorer](https://github.com/javalite/jar-explorer).  Once downloaded, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
java -jar jarexplorer-0.7-BETA.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [zipgrep](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/zipgrep.1.html) to do this and more (it will search inside the files).

Disclaimer: Not tested, feel free to downvote if it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

To Search 'qawas' String inside the jar

```
find . -iname '*.jar' -printf "unzip -c %p | grep -q 'qawas' && echo %p\n" | sh
```

or alternatively use below to find which class use

```
find . -iname '*.jar' -print | while read jar; do
  echo "$jar:"
  unzip -qq -l $jar | sed 's/.* //' | while read cls; do
    unzip -c $jar $cls | grep -q 'Tag read' && echo "   "$cls
  done
done
```